# Disable "middle click to lower window" behaviour on gnome

Tags: mouse, window-manager

I am using the Chromium web browser, and standard gnome (i.e. not unity). Chromium (like lots of things) has many tabs, and allows you to middle click on a tab to close the tab. But if I middle click on the blue part outside the tab, then it lowers the window underneath all the other windows. However I often find myself attempting to middle click on a tab to close it, and accidentally middle clicking outside the tab (which is the title bar in chromium), and hence accidentally lowering the window.

How do I disable this "middle click to lower window" behaviour?

Comment: Are you using GNOME Shell, GNOME Classic, or GNOME Classic without effects? I'm asking because each of these uses a different window manager, and the setting you want is attached to the window manager.

Answer (score 14):

For 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) it could be disabled with the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-middle-click-titlebar 'none'
```

Restore original state:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-middle-click-titlebar 'lower'
```

Also, the following variants are possible:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-middle-click-titlebar 'toggle-shade'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-middle-click-titlebar 'maximize'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-middle-click-titlebar 'toggle-maximize-horizontally'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-middle-click-titlebar 'toggle-maximize-vertically'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-middle-click-titlebar 'minimize'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-middle-click-titlebar 'shade'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-middle-click-titlebar 'menu'
```

But [the bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59159/disable-middle-click-to-lower-window-behaviour-on-gnome#comment180510_59162) is still there, option from the Google Chrome Settings "Use system title bar and borders" could lower the impact...

Comment: I was curious what the `'*shade'` options do, so I tried them out on Ubuntu 14.04. `'shade'` is `"outside of valid range"`, and `'toggle-shade'` seems to have no effect. Drat the luck! They sounded interesting. :)

Comment: FWIW this works on 18.04 as well (though I didn't test the variants, just 'none')

Answer (score 8):

You can install [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) and there should be a setting for it.

You can also get at it through `gconf-editor`. Go to apps > metacity > general > action_middle_click_titlebar and set it to "none". This value, "none", is case sensitive.

Comment: Your solution works (also for Unity) but it seems Google Chrome is a special case and has a bug. It ignores the middle mouse system settings (all other programs are fine) for the bar where the tabs are located. I will try to make a bug report at chromium :-/

Comment: @therealmarv Good catch. I can confirm this behavior on my machine. A bug report seems to be in order.

Comment: here is my bug report on this: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132061

Comment: and 5 years later, this bug is still a thing -_-

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume that you are using GNOME Shell. You can change this setting using a tool called gnome-tweak-tool, which appears as "Advanced Settings" in the activities overview.

First, install [gnome-tweak-tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gnome-tweak-tool) using Software Center.

Once it is installed, go to the Activities overview, type "Advanced Settings," and open the application that appears.

You can configure lots of things in this tool, but the one you're interested in is in the Windows section on the left side. Click that, and change "Action on title bar middle-click" to whatever you want.

[image: gnome-tweak-tool's window settings panel]

Answer (score 3):

This works for Chromium:

```
gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/metacity/general/action_middle_click_titlebar "none"
```

Comment: On my machine (regular Ubuntu 16.04), this is under a different setting. For me that would be `gconftool-2 --type string --set /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/action_middle_click_titlebar "none"`.

Comment: There's lot of weird invisible characters in the command above so it will fail. The command without these weird characters is: `gconftool-2 --type string --set /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/action_middle_click_titlebar "none"`

Comment: It might be better to just use `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-middle-click-titlebar none`. Note that you may need to log out for Chrome / Chromium to notice the change.

Comment: Minor correction: Chrome (53.0.2785.113) respects the setting, but Chromium (52.0.2743.116) doesn't for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone wants to turn this on, there's a bug affecting it on recent Cinnamon. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=777821.

The work around:
Manually create a .config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini with:

```
[Settings]
gtk-titlebar-middle-click=lower
```

Then restart chrome with chrome://restart

Answer (score 1):

As of Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS this problem is solved using `$ gnome-tweaks` window/middle and just clicking to none.

Comment: Additionally (and in 22.04), gnome-tweaks allows one to easily choose to use area clicks or multi-finger clicks. I largely prefer multi-finger clicks, where two fingers right clicks and three fingers middle clicks. It's must more natural and predictable. Without this, I was closing browser tabs instead of switching to them on accident, and this accident was easy to fall into.