Anyone figured out how to lower an application window on X11 on Ubuntu 24.04.1?
I started on Ubuntu 8.04 LTS and I've come to heavily rely on middle-clicking the Title bar of the foreground application in order to reveal applications hidden behind. However, after upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04.1 a few days ago, I find that this feature works only on Wayland. When I revert to X11 (due to applications that I depend on not working on Wayland such as Shutter and Gpick to name a few), this feature no longer works.
My current workaround is to use the Super key to spread all currently running applications on the current screen then selecting the one I'm after.
Has anyone here figured out how to make this feature operational on Ubuntu 24.04.1 when using X11?
EDIT: Clarification
Let's say I run 2 applications in full screen mode.  Previously, there have been 3 options to switch to the other app:

alt+tab
Win+S to spread applications and use arrow keys
middle-click title bar of foreground application

Using any of these 3 options I could switch to the other application up until Ubuntu 22.04.  However, it now appears that the 3rd option is no longer working when using X11 on Ubuntu 24.04.

Thanks for the clarification, I still don't understand which effect middle-clicking the title bar has, though. ;)

It's been an on/off issue over the life of Ubuntu where it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.  See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/59159/disable-middle-click-to-lower-window-behaviour-on-gnome.  In there, the user is trying to disable the setting.  For me, my muscle memory relies on it being on.

Maybe it's time I started posting videos to my YouTube channel.

What do you mean by "reveal"? Is the Window just becoming transparent (but not losing focus) or is it sent to the background, behind all the windows it is blocking?
I know of a similar feature by Compiz (which I am using with X11). It's called "Visibility" and works like this:
When you move your mouse cursor above a window which is partially covered by one or several foreground windows, the foreground windows will become translucent, so you can see through them and fully see the window which you hover with your mouse cursor. The foreground window which had focus doesn't loose it, it just becomes translucent. When you move your cursor back over the foreground window, the translucency is reverted. You can configure the transparency level (between 0 and 100%) and also set a timeout before the effect sets in.
I find this feature extremely useful (for example, you can type in the translucent foreground window and at the same time see what's in the background window). But I'm not sure if it would solve the problem for you...
Also, in order to use it, you'd have to switch to Compiz as window manager. If you are using Gnome, this won't work, you'd have to switch to another DE like Mate or Xfce.

I believe you should have posted this as a comment for clarification as what you suggest here isn't it.  I'll add more context to the question shortly.

I see. Well the text wouldn't fit into a single comment, also, possibly other users will find it helpful in their case when stumbling upon this question.
